# What color scheme is this

Tags: color-scheme, text-editor, code

I'd appreciate some info on (the exact, an underlying or a similar) color scheme used for styling code samples on this page:

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4

I'd like to get or (re)create a version of it for my code editor

Comment: Hello @jaam, and welcome to UX.SE. Unfortunately, this gets into implementation of user interfaces, which isn't considered on-topic here. The best chance of finding this answer is probably contacting their support team directly.

Comment: It's called "syntax highlighting" and there are many variations. Many code editors have it as an option you can enable and some even allow you to customize it.

Comment: @NathanRabe Indeed. I was looking for the tag but there was none

Comment: @jaam It's not really a UX topic. There is a tag for it over on https://stackoverflow.com/ and you can probably find some helpful answers there.

Comment: @NathanRabe I'm not sure. My question is about a color scheme (quite independently of its usage, even just getting color codes would be fine). SO is focused on programming (like getting syntax highlighting to work in IDEs, etc.). My specific use case is UX in programming in a text editor w/ syntax highlighting, so UX is a pretty good match

Answer (score 1):

This feature is called [syntax highlighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_highlighting):

> Syntax highlighting is one strategy to improve the readability and context of the text; especially for code that spans several pages. The reader can easily ignore large sections of comments or code, depending on what they are looking for. Syntax highlighting also helps programmers find errors in their program.

It's [widespread in the Stack Exchange network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314554/295232), but not on this site, presumably because we do Q&A about UX design problems and not implementation, so we don't need that much code.

There are several libraries you can use to enable syntax highlighting; Stack Exchange [recently switched from Google Prettify to highlight.js](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353983/295232). I'm not sure what library your example is using; it *could* be that their code samples are pregenerated from a documentation tool (this has the advantage of loading faster than Stack Exchange's highlighting which happens upon page load). You can just copy over the color codes from your browser's developer tools (e.g. the orange color for HTML attribute names is `#ffa94d`) and (depending on the library) [use them in a custom CSS file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46380887/4751173).